# Weird side effect using operator '->' in c

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, side-effects

I get this weird side effect while using operator '->' in code I wrote in C. The pointer which I used -> on , is changed to have some garbage.

More specifically:

I have the following structs:

```
typedef void* ListElement ;

typedef  struct List_t* List ;

typedef struct Node_t* Node;

Struct Node_t {
  ListElement data ;
  Node next;
}

Struct List_t {
  Node* head;
  Node* current
}
```

when I use the following `ListGetFirst()`, I get wired behavior :

```
ListElement ListGetFirst(List list)
{
  if( list == NULL || list->head==NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  list->current=list->head;
  Node* head =list->head; // here is the problem
  ListElement data = (*head)->data;
  return data;
}
```

when I used debugger I figured out that the pointer list->head is changed on the marked aformentioned line .

I realy have no idea why, and I didn't knew that '->' can have side effect

thanks in advance

Comment: Most likely you're misinterpreting what's happening.

Comment: No, -> does not have side effects in C.  Why not just do `return list->head->data`?

Comment: It is your code, and not a "side effect" of `->`. That much is certain.

Comment: @meagar - if thats my code , please help me find the answer, I'm desprate

Comment: You just shouldn't use typedefs that hide the fact that the types are pointers. We all get confused by that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gah, pointers hidden behind typedefs; unless the type's meant to be totally opaque, that's almost always bad juju.  For my benefit, I'm going to take out the typedefs so I have an easier time seeing what you're really playing with.

```
struct Node_t {   
  void *data ;   
  struct Node_t *next; 
};

struct List_t {   
  struct Node_t **head;   
  struct Node_t **current; 
};

void *ListGetFirst(struct List_t *list)
{
  if( list == NULL || list->head==NULL
  {        
     return NULL;
  }
  list->current=list->head;             
  struct Node_t **head =list->head; // here is the problem
  void *data = (*head)->data;
  return data;           
}
```

I got nuthin'.  Types all appear to match up.  The `->` operator most emphatically **does not** have any side effects; all it does is dereference a pointer.  The extra level of indirection for `head` and `current` in `struct List_t` is a head-scratcher, and it makes me wonder if they're being allocated or assigned correctly. All I can figure is that `list->head` isn't pointing to memory that you actually own, and is getting overwritten somehow when you reach that point (IOW, you've invoked undefined behavior somewhere else in your code).

In short, the problem isn't in the code that you've posted.  It's probably where you allocate and assign list elements.

Comment: Thanks , thats the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 9):

Are you sure this is exactly what you want to do?

```
typedef struct Node_t* Node;

Node* head =list->head;
```

Since you defined Node as a pointer to Node_t, shouldn't you be doing:

```
Node head =list->head;
```

**EDIT**:

To summarize the whole thing, I think this typedef is misleading you:

```
typedef struct Node_t* Node;
```

It would made more sense if it were simply:

```
typedef struct Node_t Node;
```

Comment: @karlphillip - look at the struct . I decided to have in the list_t struct Node* variables , and not Node.

Comment: I think Karl has this; you are using Node* which is the address of the pointer, not the pointers value which would be the address of the list.

Comment: @RanZilber What you are doing on your code is equivalent to `Node_t** head = list->head;` and you clearly need to do `Node_t* head = list->head;`, **which can be achieved with** `Node head = list->head;`

Comment: @karlphillip - but list->head is of type Node* , or Node_t** , thats how I defined it .

Comment: And then you can do ListElement data = head->data;

Comment: @Mario The Spoon - The type is still wrong. @karlphillip - Well , I cant change it. Thats how I got it , and it has to remain the same. Thefore , the typdef must stay the same , and so does the struct. When that in mind , do you think you can find any other problem rather that on the code?

Comment: Yes! Use `Node head =list->head;` instead. The code is broken. If you got it like that and you want to make it work, you'll have to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using pointers to pointers, where most likely you want pointers.

In List_t you define head as Node*, where Node is already a Node_t* .

hth

Mario

Comment: Isn't that what I posted in my answer 4 min ago? =P

Comment: @Mario The Spoon - I was asked to built the list like that. I know that its weird and a better solution would be to built it with just one pointer - but im bounded to this solution . Why that should be a problem ?

Comment: @karlphillip: grrrrrrrrrr ;-)

Comment: @RanZilber: what was the requirement that forces you to do that? It just doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @Mario, did they ask you to do a doubly linked list ?)

Comment: @Jens: you meant RanZilber, I assume?